# How to add a user to apache group on Mac Os X?

Tags: macos, apache

I'm actually trying to run Symfony2 on my MacBook Pro (Mac OS X 10.6).

When i launch my application by apache, all cache and log file are created by the _www:_www user/group.
But, i already have to edit these files in the CLI, with my own user.

My question is : how to add my user to the _www group ?

I have tried to edit the /etc/group to add my user name to _www group, restart apache : fail
I have also tried to edit /etc/apache2/httpd.conf to change user and group used by Apache : complete error acces.

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: This is more of a Superuser questions. The answer is to use the dseditgroup command. Details are here: http://superuser.com/questions/214004/how-to-add-user-to-a-group-from-mac-os-x-command-line/214311#214311

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a your_username -t user _www
```

Comment: where `ikr` is the username to add to group `_www`

Comment: And now `ikr` has been edited to `your_username`... or maybe that's making it obvious what the command does... idk...

Answer (score 45):

I'd suggest the same as above but here's a bit more copy/paste friendly version:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a `whoami` -t user _www
```

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the same issue just to make it global on your personal mac not production i would suggest to run this and you will never have to do chmod again

`sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a _www -t user staff`